Типизация функции, работающей с разными типами данных
Есть функция, работающая с массивами, содержащими 2 типа данных (дженерик): Movie<Image>[] или Movie<string>[], так как она использует одинаковые поля, имеющиеся у них.
Использую вложенные интерфейсы, так как на вход поступает массив вложенных объектов - movies, который затем сохраняется в БД измененным (остаются нужные поля, убирается вложенность) и опять используется, как savedMovies. Дженерик и поля с ? используются, чтобы применить Movie и там, и там.
interface Image {
  url:string;
  formats:Formats
}

interface Formats {
  thumbnail:Thumbnail
}

interface Thumbnail {
  url:string;
}

interface Movie<T> {
  id?: number;
  movieId?:number;
  nameRU: string;
  nameEN: string;
  director: string;
  country: string;
  year: string;
  duration: number;
  description: string;
  trailerLink?: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  image: T;
  thumbnail?:string;
  trailer?:string;
  owner?:number;
}

Сама функция:
  function findMovies(movies: Movie<Image>[]|Movie<string>[], word:string, isChecked:Boolean) {
    return movies.filter((movie) => {
      return finder(movie, word, isChecked);
    });
  }

Соответственно, возвращает она тоже:
 Movie<Image>[]|Movie<string>[]

Результат ее выполнения используют 2 других функции:
  function handleUpdateFindWord(word:string, isChecked:Boolean) {
    const filteredRes: Movie<Image>[] = findMovies(movies, word, isChecked);
    ...
  }

и
  function handleFindSavedMovies(word:string, isChecked:Boolean) {
    const filteredMovies: Movie<string>[] = findMovies(savedMovies, word, isChecked);
    ...
  }

Но обе они ожидают от findMovies НЕ Movie<Image>[]|Movie<string>[], а что-то одно:
Type '(Movie<Image> | Movie<string>)[]' is not assignable to type 'Movie<Image>[]'.
  Type 'Movie<Image> | Movie<string>' is not assignable to type 'Movie<Image>'.
    Type 'Movie<string>' is not assignable to type 'Movie<Image>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Image'.ts(2322)

Я понял, что могу создать отдельную функцию, типа findMovies для второго типа, чтобы не использовать Movie<Image>[]|Movie<string>[] в них. Или добавить Movie<Image>[]|Movie<string>[] в обе функции, но дальше эти данные идут в другие функции по цепочке и теряется смысл от создания дженерика. Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ типизации здесь?

А вот с такими интерфейсами проблема таки воспроизвелась

Ну а вообще вы сами и написали ответ на свой вопрос — создать дженерик function findMovies<M extends Movie<Image>|Movie<string>>(movies: M[], word:string, isChecked:Boolean): M[] {

Принципиальная разница между movies и savedMovies в том, что в savedMovies image извлечен из вложенного объекта как его поле url (строка), извлечен из того же объекта thumbnail и добавлен owner (ObjectId из mongo), пока не разобрался как его типизировать, но пока приложение не запускается думаю это не влияет, пока поставил number.

Пока что есть ощущение, что вы просто решили создать себе проблем на ровном месте. Зачем кого-то куда-то извлекать вообще и что помешало просто хранить вложенный объект как есть?

Или вот такой вариант похоже более универсальный — больше дженериков богу дженериков function findMovies<T extends Image|string, M extends Movie<T>>(movies: M[], word:string, isChecked:Boolean): M[] {

Чтобы не типизировать всю эту вложенность, хранить меньше в БД. Это проект для портфолио, хотелось, чтобы все было красиво. Но я могу ошибаться.

Зачем тогда вся эта вложенность вообще нужна? Пока что непонятно, что вообще вы пытаетесь сделать, но зато понятно, что сам факт существования Movie<T> ну никак нельзя назвать красивым

Тех. задание и, в частности, структура данных не мной была определена. Как дополнение я решил типизировать мой проект...Но я же уменьшаю размер кода за счет дженерика. Использование его именно так или именно здесь неуместно?

Внутри Movie<T> ещё и thumbnail зачем-то дублируется, который вроде как уже есть внутри Image. В общем, в текущем виде так и чешутся руки выкинуть все эти Image, Formats и Thumbnail как бессмысленно усложняющие код (если, конечно, у них нет какого-то скрытого смысла, о котором я не в курсе)
